# Como se convierte una lista de tipo clase a otro tipo de claseTO en java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Estoy iniciando en el desarrollo de java web con `spring-boot` y me pidieron que convirtiera mi `array` de tipo `Empresa` a uno de tipo de `EmpresaTO` antes de devolver el resultado.

```
@Service
public class EmpresasRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private final ConvertidorHelper cnvHelper = new ConvertidorHelper();
    private List<EmpresaTO> empTO;
    public List<Empresa> buscar_empresas(EmpresaTO empresasTO) {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        final StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = session.createStoredProcedureQuery("buscar_empresas", Empresa.class);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.setParameter(1, empresasTO.getStrBusquedaEmpresa());
        storedProcedure.setParameter(2, cnvHelper.obtenerInteger(empresasTO.getIntIdEmpresa()));

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final List<Empresa> resq = storedProcedure.getResultList();

        session.close();


        return resq;
    }
}
```

Comment: Una de las maneras podrias ser iterar sobre la tú lista de empresa e ir convirtiendo uno a uno a la entidad Dto despues agregar ésto a una Lista del tipo Dto.

Comment: pero como seria eso? ya que los datos del procedimiento almacenado llegan en una cadena

Comment: final List<Empresa> resq = storedProcedure.getResultList(); en éste punto tienes un lista de Empresas es correcto eso verdad?

Comment: así es en la variable resq estoy recibiendo el resultado de la consulta

Comment: Te paso un link que te puede ser de ayuda https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application, si te quedan algunas dudas, podes modificar tú pregunta y agregar por ejemplo tú DTO.